# Find Python packages on pypi.org importing a certain package

Tags: python, pypi

To learn from the source code of other Python packages, I am looking for Python packages on [www.pypi.org](http://www.pypi.org) that import `concurrent.futures`.

How can I find such packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `concurrent.futures` modules is part of the standard library, so what you're asking for is a way to search the source of all packages on PyPI, which isn't currently possible.

You might want to try using GitHub code search instead: https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=%22concurrent.futures%22&type=Code

Comment: Thanks for the answer. An alternative would be to download the source files and search through them locally. But with a mirror size of more than 10TB this is time consuming...